# What cairo function produces a clickable url

Tags: cairo

I'm trying to use cairo to output www.google.com as a clickable url in my pdf document.  Does anyone know of a cairo function that will do this?  I'm searching for uri and url at [cairo manual index](http://cairographics.org/manual/index-all.html)and this showed up. I don't think that's it, is it? It looks like I'd use that to show a picture.

CAIRO_MIME_TYPE_URI, CAIRO_MIME_TYPE_URI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cairo cannot do clickable URLs in a PDF, sorry